# Serialization of derived class from templated class versioning

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, versioning

I'm trying to serialize a class derived from a template class, where I fix the template argument. I want to serialize the base class independently from the derived one in case I fix the template to some other type and I want the derived class to serialize to base class plus some other data. When I do this in my minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <boost/serialization/split_member.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/traits.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/level.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>

using namespace boost::archive;
static constexpr unsigned int base_version = 1;

template<typename T>
struct Base : public boost::serialization::traits<Base<T>,
                                                 boost::serialization::object_class_info,
                                                 boost::serialization::track_never,
                                                 base_version> {
  T t;
  template<typename A>
  void load(A& a,
            unsigned int const in_version) {
    std::cerr << "Loading Base with version " << in_version  << std::endl;
    a & t;
  }
  template<typename A>
  void save(A& a,
            unsigned int const) const {
    std::cerr << "Saving Base with version " << base_version << std::endl;
    a & t;
  }
  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
};

struct Derived : public Base<int> {
  int j;
  static constexpr unsigned int version = 2;
  template<typename A>
  void load(A& a,
            unsigned int const in_version) {
    std::cerr << "Loading Derived with version " << in_version << std::endl;
    a & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
    a & j;
  }
  template<typename A>
  void save(A& a,
            unsigned int const) const {
    std::cerr << "Saving Derived with version " << version << std::endl;
    a & boost::serialization::base_object<Base>(*this);
    a & j;
  }
  BOOST_SERIALIZATION_SPLIT_MEMBER()
};
BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(Derived,Derived::version)

int main() {
  Derived d;
  d.t = 1;

  std::stringstream s;
  text_oarchive oa {s};
  oa << d;

  Derived e;
  text_iarchive ia{s};
  ia >> e;
  std::cerr << e.t << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I get as an output:

```
Saving Derived with version 2
Saving Base with version 1
Loading Derived with version 2
Loading Base with version 2
1
```

It seems that the saving is done with the correct versions, while the load is always done with the version of the derived class. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

Defining the version of Base not via inheritance but by specialising a member of the `boost::serialization` namespace leads to the desired behaviour for me:

```
// headers as before
#define BOOST_CLASS_TEMPLATE_VERSION(Template, Type, Version) \
namespace boost {                                           \
  namespace serialization {                                 \
    template<Template>                                      \
    struct version<Type> {                                  \
      static constexpr unsigned int value = Version;        \
    };                                                      \
    template<Template>                                      \
    constexpr unsigned int version<Type>::value;            \
  }                                                         \
}

using namespace boost::archive;
static constexpr unsigned int base_version = 1;

template<typename T>
struct Base {
  T t;
// ...
};
BOOST_CLASS_TEMPLATE_VERSION(typename T, Base<T>, base_version);
// rest as before
```

gives

```
$ ./main 
Saving Derived with version 2
Saving Base with version 1
Loading Derived with version 2
Loading Base with version 1
1
```

with Boost 1.67.